# Topological realization of fiber sequences of motivic spaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, motivic-homotopy

Consider the realization functor $t^{\mathbb{C}}:H^{mot}\to H^{top}$ from the unstable motivic homotopy category with base field $\mathbb{C}$ to the homotopy category of topological spaces.
In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.08857), Wickelgren and Williams point out that $t^{\mathbb{C}}$ is the derived functor of the left adjoint of a Quillen adjunction, and it does not preserve homotopy fiber sequences in general.

So, is there an example of a homotopy fiber sequence in $H^{mot}$ such that its image under $t^{\mathbb{C}}$ is not a homotopy fiber sequence?